# How to add multiple joinCondition in vis.js while clustering

Tags: vis.js

I am using vis.js for network diagramming, I need to cluster some nodes. 
For Example: create new cluster when a node property is 'aaa' (Suppose two nodes has 'aaa' they will create cluster). 
Again create new cluster when a node property is 'bbb' (Suppose two nodes has 'bbb' they will create another cluster).

I have two problems:
1) I don't want to hard-code 'aaa' or 'bbb'. 
2) I don't want to create multiple clusterOptionsByData object and invoke network.cluster(clusterOptionsByData) multiple times.
Is there any way to pass multiple joinconditions while clustering in  vis.js?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the developer of the visjs network. The answer to 2) is no.

What is the use case of not wanting to call the method twice? You can construct your own join condition based on variables and pass that into the cluster method. You don't need to hardcore anything.

Every cluster call makes one cluster. Multiple join conditions do not make sense. It's up to you to come up with a good join condition that covers all your cases.

Next time you have a question, post it on our github issues page. We get email updates on these so we'd be able to help you quicker.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Alexdm. I invoked the network.cluster(clusterOptionsByData) in loop. Though my objective is achieved, but performance is reduced.

Comment: I'm afraid that is the price we pay for safety... There have been many issues with a single node being in two clusters. If there really a noticeable performance issue here thought? I believe clustering is very fast at the moment.